# Long CASE statement- is it written as effectively as it can be?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running a stored procedure in order to pull a report of all the recent sales from end of March and will need the report to remain daily updated until early May (this is a specific sales period in here).

Everything had been ran in Access before I started, so this is my attempt at moving big reports into SQL.

The stored procedure is working fine, but there are numerous sales channels which are determined by other parts of the data and, so this is where the CASE statement comes in. Some of the data is pulling as channels I am not expecting it to and overall it is just very long, so I don't know if it could maybe look neater? it could be something simple like adding brackets but I am pretty much self-taught in SQL and I am looking to pick up good habits and learn from others to see!

```
CASE 
        WHEN mop = 0
            AND Channel = 'Internet'
            AND financeinstal = 10
            THEN 'Finance option 10 months'
        WHEN mop = 0
            AND Channel = 'Internet'
            AND financeinstal = 4
            THEN 'Finance option 4'
        WHEN Channel = 'Corporate'
            OR pb = 'PR Department'
            THEN 'Corporate'
        WHEN Channel = 'Call Centre'
            OR username = 'call centre'
            AND mop = 3
            OR mop = 4
            THEN 'Call Centre'
        WHEN Channel = 'Internet'
            AND username = 'InternetUser'
            AND mop = 3
            OR mop = 4
            THEN 'Internet'
        WHEN Channel = 'Premium'
            OR Channel = 'Premium Office'
            THEN 'Premium'
        WHEN Channel = 'Ticket Office'
            AND MOP = 1
            OR MOP = 2
            OR MOP = 3
            OR MOP = 4
            THEN 'Ticket Office (Full Payment)'
        WHEN mop_desc = 'Direct Debit'
            AND mop = 8
            THEN 'Automatic'
        WHEN Channel = 'Ticket'
            THEN 'Ticket'
        ELSE 'Other'
        END AS Sales_Channel
```

So, i'm expecting the results to be as I have put them in the CASE, but, e.g. some I would expect to come back as Internet is coming back as Call Centre

Comment: you question is not clear  .. try add  a proper data sample your expected  result and your actual result

Comment: Are you aware of `OR` and `AND` operators' precedence?

Comment: Hi @Danielle if your're looking to remove thoses big CASE statement you have solution to build Reference Datatable with all condition and excepted output Name and after that you have only to JOIN this with your current table

Comment: Instead of these many cases, why dont you put that in a table and do a join. That would be better in terms of maintenance and readability. You can then use these keys for the join 
mop,  Channel, financeinstal

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure you have some errors.  You should use parentheses when missing `and` and `or`.  Or, better yet, use `in`.

For instance:

```
WHERE Channel = 'Internet' AND
      username = 'InternetUser' AND
      mop = 3 OR
      mop = 4
```

should probably be:

```
WHERE Channel = 'Internet' AND
      username = 'InternetUser' AND
      mop IN (3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to re-write the case statement as a join to an inline table which will be faster

for example the first 2 case statements could be re-writen like this

```
with lookup(mop,channel,finance,return)
AS
(
   SELECT 0, 'Internet', 10, 'Finance option 10 months'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 0, 'Internet', 4, 'Finance option 4'
)
SELECT 
 -- etc
 -- instead of case
 L.return 
 -- etc
FROM base
JOIN lookup AS L on base.mop = L.mop AND base.Channel = L.channel AND base.financeinstal = L.finance
```

Comment: as a note -- or is simple -- it is just another line with the other value where the OR is needed and the same value in the return.

Answer (score 0):

`AND` has higher operator precedence than `OR`. So in absence of parenthesis, `AND` are evaluated together, and then `OR`.

Think of operator's precedence as how sticky the conditions will be if there are no parenthesis used. So with this:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop = 3 OR mop = 4`
```

This sticks together:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop = 3
```

So the `OR mop = 4` goes on its own:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop = 3
OR 
mop = 4
```

The above is evaluated like following if expressed with explicit parenthesis:

```
(Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop = 3)
OR 
mop = 4
```

But that will produce incorrect result, likewise with parenthesis-less condition. So you need to put parenthesis in the right places to make your condition correct:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND (mop = 3 OR mop = 4)
```

SQL has a shorthand for `OR` when you want to compare a field to many values. It's the `IN` operator, it's not only useful when you have many values to compare against a field, it's also useful when you want to minimize the use of parenthesis. So instead of `OR`, use `IN`:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop IN (3,4)
```

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, and then `IN` has higher precedence than `AND`, so the above is not evaluated as:

```
(Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop) IN (3,4)
```

Instead, `IN` is evaluated first, and then `AND`. So it's evaluated like this whene explicitly written with parenthesis:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND (mop IN (3,4))
```

Since `IN` has higher precedence than `AND`, the parenthesis around `mop IN (3,4)` can be safely removed:

```
Chanel = 'Internet' AND Username = 'InternetUser' AND mop IN (3,4)
```